# Where to disable cross-network protection in Opera?

Tags: javascript, security, opera

In [JS security issue with Opera 11.01, after moving from server A to B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500548/js-security-issue-with-opera-11-01-after-moving-from-server-a-to-b) I learned that opera has some "cross-network" protection.

I encountered the same js security problem and I found that Opera 11.10 (“Barracuda”) added a preference to disable cross-network protection. My Opera is 11.50 but I can't find the specific preference.

Do I misunderstand the meaning of the "cross-network"?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is this for some internal project? Because you can't expect user to turn that setting off, too. Just stating the obvious here.

Comment: Thanks for your replay@DanMan. You are right, it's for my internal project. My online environment has not this secure problem. I guess that's because two servers are in one intranet. But in my local environment, one server is in my intranet and the other is in internet. So I want to turn that setting off to test in local environment. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Nowadays Opera is based on chromium, so you shoud use chromium way to disable `SOP` and process requests without `CORS` headers:

```
cd c:\Program Files\Opera\
launcher.exe --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="c:\nocorsbrowserdata"
```

Of course like in chromium, to make this work you should kill all your instances of `opera.exe` before starting with `--disable-web-security` flag.
If you want more details how to automate this, see [tip](https://maketips.net/tip/209/disable-cors-for-development) on my website

Comment: in case of mac `open -a Opera --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=~/emptydir`

Answer (score 3):

I believe opera:config#Network|AllowCrossNetworkNavigation is the right preference.

Comment: Thanks, this made it work. hallvors is correct though, but the other solution did not work for me.

Comment: Can't find this in the current version of opera.

Comment: "hallvors is correct though" - because, well, @hallvors WOULD be correct about anything about Opera :-)

Answer (score 1):

Disabling it entirely has security implications though - see this:
[Opera won't load some JavaScript files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464599/opera-wont-load-some-javascript-files/7442998#7442998)
for a safer workaround :)

Comment: Ah, that feeling when you have a problem, you find an answer, and it refers you to ... a question you yourself asked almost 13 years ago :-)

Comment: You've completed a full circle, @RossPatterson :D

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Unix system be careful when using "~/emptydir" for the argument value in --user-data-dir= from @palaniraja's comment on Make Tips's answer. Depending on your environment '~' might not be converted to your home directory and end up making a new directory wherever you are named '~'

I went to delete this mistake '~' directory and accidentally almost deleted my entire home directory instead out of negligence.

Try using `--user-data-dir=$HOME/emptydir` instead if you are on a Unix system.