# Permanently enable CORS in Chrome on mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, cors

Is there a way CORS can be enabled in chrome permanently, so I won't have to open the terminal and type the command `open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security` all the time?

Comment: Small comment, but I think you are asking how to *enable* CORS (cross origin resource sharing). Disabling it would actually increase the security

Answer (score 1):

@palaniraja helped to solve this in Opera on Mac (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43571952/7662526) with next command:

```
open -a Opera --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=~/emptydir
```

So please try to add `--user-data-dir=~/emptydir` to your command