# Cannot Add Event Listener

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, click, event-listener

i can add an event listener for clicks to `blank` but not to `twitter` in the code below.

```
const blank = window.open();
const twitter = window.open("https://twitter.com");

const PrintClick = function (name) {
    return function (...args) {
        console.log(name, ...args);
    };
};

blank.addEventListener("click", PrintClick("blank"));
twitter.addEventListener("click", PrintClick("twitter"));
```

is it because twitter has done something to not let me do this? would there be a way to get around it?

Comment: I think that some exception is also thrown on the console. Can you please check and update Question.

Comment: @AyushKatiyar i personally didn’t get any errors. it just fails silently ☹️

Comment: It did not fail silently It was blocked by browser. I have mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

### The reason that you did not got any exception :

Most browsers don't support multiple popups so in order to accomplish it wou need to try using:

```
window.open(yoururl,"_blank",'PopUp',randomnumber,'scrollbars=1,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=850,height=500');
```

Or Give each window a [new window name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open).

```
window.open(url, WindowName)
```

### **Security Risk**

You **can't** add an event listner with different origin using JavaScript, it would be a huge security flaw if you could do it. For the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) **browsers block scripts trying to access a frame with a different origin**.

Origin is considered different if at least one of the following parts of the address isn't maintained:

```
<protocol>://<hostname>:<port>/...
```

**Protocol**, **hostname** and **port** must be the same of your domain, if you want to access a frame.

#### Examples

Here's what would happen trying to access the following URLs from `http://www.example.com/home/index.html`

```
URL                                             RESULT 
http://www.example.com/home/other.html       -> Success 
http://www.example.com/dir/inner/another.php -> Success 
http://www.example.com:80                    -> Success (default port for HTTP) 
http://www.example.com:2251                  -> Failure: different port 
http://data.example.com/dir/other.html       -> Failure: different hostname 
https://www.example.com/home/index.html:80   -> Failure: different protocol
ftp://www.example.com:21                     -> Failure: different protocol & port 
https://google.com/search?q=james+bond       -> Failure: different protocol, port & hostname
```

**Not recommended**

### Disabling same-origin policy in *your* browser

I'll link the relative answer. However, please remember that **disabling the same-origin policy will only affect *your* browser**. Also, running a browser with same-origin security settings disabled grants *any* website access to cross-origin resources, so **it's very unsafe and should NEVER be done if you do not know exactly what you are doing (e.g. development purposes)**.

- [Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3102819/3889449)
- [Mozilla Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17088609/3889449)
- [Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4556429/3889449)
- [Opera](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7543678/3889449)
- Microsoft Edge: [not possible](https://superuser.com/q/1020612/591004)
- [Microsoft Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20947359/3889449)

Comment: thanks a lot for your very clear and helpful answer. is this also why [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60725633/8966013) didn’t work? i was trying to copy and paste some javascript into the console while i have the website open and click a button through javascript

Comment: @MinAndyChoi There are 2 problems with your sollution. Please refer to answer I have updated my answer.

Comment: @MinAndyChoi https://javascript.info/cross-window-communication article that you can refer to.

Answer (score 0):

addEventListener can only listen to the dom object of the current page, you can consider selenium automation framework operations

Comment: but my code has successfully added an event listener for clicks to `blank` though. if i go to the blank window and click in random places the original window logs those clicks to the console. it just doesn’t work with twitter

Comment: same origin policy

Comment: is there a way to turn that off?

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons browsers disable any interaction across domains that you do not own. Imagine all the things one could do with that.

Comment: i see that now. is it also why [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60725633/8966013) didn’t work? i was trying to copy and paste javascript into the console while i have the twitter website open and click a button through the code